# Simple login form with Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm starting to work with Retrofit but I'm stuck on this simple step. I have a login form and I'm trying to authenticate with the server but I just can't send the request.

This is what I've tried:

My Retrofit client:

```
private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
        new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
    Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(httpClient.build()).build();
    return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
}
```

My login interface:

```
public interface Login {

    @POST(LOGIN)
    Call<String> loginWithCredentials(@Body LoginCredentials data);
}
```

The LoginCredentials class:

```
public class LoginCredentials {

    private String name;
    private String pass;

    public LoginCredentials(String name, String pass) {
        this.name = name;
        this.pass = pass;
    }
}
```

And the part where I call it:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    showProgress(true);

    String username = userField.getText().toString();
    String password = passField.getText().toString();

    ApiController.Login loginClient = ApiController.createService(ApiController.Login.class);
    Call<String> call =loginClient.loginWithCredentials(new LoginCredentials(username, password));
    call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
            handleResponse(response.body());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
            showProgress(false);
            Log.e(TAG, t.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    });

}
```

And I keep getting the error `Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $`but I have no idea what it means.

Comment: can you post an example of what your server is actually returning?

Comment: My server returns a String if the request is successful. A String used as the api token, like this: 7ec16632-e1f4-4787-91f4-7279ce6c48d2

Comment: Okay, I think we need to see your `handleResponse` code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured it out. It was easier than I thought. You can skip the parsing that `Retrofit` does by setting the response type of the method as `ResponseBody`. Them you just need to read the response and use the `string()` method that provides. That's it!

**Example:**

```
public interface Login {
    @POST(LOGIN)
    Call<ResponseBody> loginWithCredentials(@Body LoginCredentials data);
}
```

Then use like this:

```
String username = userField.getText().toString();
String password = passField.getText().toString();

ApiController.Login loginClient = ApiController.createService(ApiController.Login.class);
Call<ResponseBody> call = loginClient.loginWithCredentials(new LoginCredentials(username, password));
call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            try {
                // get String from response
                String stringResponse = response.body().string();
                // Do whatever you want with the String
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
        // handle error
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This error means that gson trying to parse string from server as JSON object and can't find the opening bracket.

I think you could return actual JSON from server like

```
{"api_token": "token"}
```

Also this bug could possibly be solved by importing latest GSON version mentioned [here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1151#issuecomment-188222490)

Comment: Is there a way I can read the String from the response as it is? I'm not sure I'm able to mess with the server just now. Basically what I want is send the POST request with my data object and receive a String. Is that possible?

Comment: Did you tried solution from the link from my answer? in short, you could add latest gson to your build.gradle and then use it while building retrofit `.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new Gson()))`